# Access Hulu within the US while using a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing

My situation appears to be 'backwards' from the normal Split Tunneling solutions. I want ALL traffic (except Hulu) to use my VPN. This way, Hulu can confirm I am a real-honest US user and allow viewing. I use a VPN for security but willing to allow Hulu access.

I created a specific IP address for Hulu in my hosts file so I could route. Then I tried to set a non-VPN gateway for that address. Didn't work. Maybe I'm not sure what the real non-VPN gateway address is ... or maybe Hulu is playing more games. More likely, I'm not setting it up correctly.

I'm not a network expert and likely doing something wrong. Neither Hulu nor my VPN provider will provide any assistance. Not trying to circumvent any Hulu rules since I'm trying to make Hulu use my REAL IP.

Can someone assist me?

Mes - Win 7 Pro - Private Internet Access VPN -
private network (192.168.x.x) on a Linksys router on TWC's network in CA.

Comment: I kept working on this and believe I found the solution. As it turns out, I was using the wrong gateway address for the route. Haven't tested Hulu yet, but it's working with two popular "what is my Ip address" sites. It also appears to work more reliability if I add the route then make the VPN connection.

Answer (score 0):

> I created a specific IP address for Hulu in my hosts file so I could route. Then I tried to set a non-VPN gateway for that address. Didn't work. Maybe I'm not sure what the real non-VPN gateway address is ... or maybe Hulu is playing more games. More likely, I'm not setting it up correctly.

You miss stepped here. That will prevent DNS resolving Hulus connections and operating.

What you'd want to do normally is route block X through your regular gateway(TWC modem) over-riding the default route added by PIA. BUT, that won't work in this case as Hulu uses CDNs, so you would need to route for Hulus IP space, Akamais IP space, Adobes IP space etc etc.

If the PIA client lets you exempt a program, pick a browser and exempt it, then use it for Hulu and nothing else. AFAIK it doesnt though.

Comment: Thanks Line4ult. As you mentioned, it became overwhelming to route all of Hulu's CDN's. I wasn't aware some VPN clients allow program exemption. I will investigate this more.